# Why 1%2 results in 1 in JavaScript while when I divide 1 by 2 normally you get 0 as the remainder?

Tags: javascript, modulo, integer-division

So I know this question seems kind of stupid, but recently I was going through some JS questions and I happen to do `1 % 2` in the browser console and I got `1`, while when I did 1 divided by 2 on a paper I got the reminder `0`. I am well aware of the concept that the value returned is the reminder, but why is it different in JavaScript and when I do on a paper ? Is there any underlying concept of JS that I'm not aware about ?

Comment: what... you're doing the paper division wrong. (the question is not answerable because of that...)

Comment: are you *sure* you did your math right?  `1/2 = 0.5`, `2/1 = 1.0`.  Quite the difference.

Comment: What are you trying to calculate?

Comment: @advertmanagerpro.com I was going through some JS questions and while working it out, I stumbled upon getting different answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in case of the MODULUS Operator(`%`) if the first number  is smaller than the second number then it returns the first number itself.

Here is an interactive snippet to test it out!

```js
const n1 = document.getElementById("n1");
const n2 = document.getElementById("n2");
const result = document.getElementById("result");

function modulus() {
  result.innerText = Number(Number(n1.value) % Number(n2.value));
}

function division() {
  result.innerText = Number(Number(n1.value) / Number(n2.value));
}
```

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="First Number" id="n1">
<br>
<br>
<input type="number" placeholder="Second Number" id="n2">
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="modulus()">Modules(%)</button>
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="division()">Division(/)</button>
<br>
<br>
<b>Result</b>
<br>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am well aware of the concept that the value returned is the reminder

I don't think so. Remainder is the number which is left over or remaining in the division. When one number is not divisible by other there will always be a remainder.

In the case when dividend (the number being divided) is less than divisor (the number by which we divide) the remainder will always be the smaller number which is the dividend.